# Get Expression from List<Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>>>

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having problems coming up with a function to dynamically generate predicates for my EF6 based web app.

I need to pass this type into an already existing function:

`Expression<Func<MyModelType, bool>>`

It is for a search so i need to build the query based on what fields and search terms are part of the search. I tried the below to but I cant get it to be dynamic, it always includes all search terms regardless of whether a search term exists, in example below i always want to search for searchTerm1 in Field1 but only do the searchTerm2 part if a value exists for it, but the EF query is including this part of the query anyway regardless so it results in a slow search.

```
Expression<Func<MyModelType, bool>> predicates = null;

predicates = (
        p => (
        p.Field1.ToString().ToLower() == (searchTerm1.ToLower())
        )
        &&
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm2) || (
        p.Field1.ToString().Contains(searchTerm2)
        ||
        p.Field2.ToString().Contains(searchTerm2.ToLower())))
);
```

I want it in a way such that i can do:

```
If(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm1))
query.Add(q=>q.FieldX.Equals(searchTerm1)

If(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm2))
query.Add(q=>q.FieldCountry.Equals(searchTerm2)

If(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm3))
query.Add(q=>q.Keywords.Contains(searchTerm3)
```

etc etc just a way to have contriol over what is and isn't in the Expression query.
I have created a List of `Expression<Func<MyEntity,bool>>` but i cant then convert that to a single expression to pass to my function.

Comment: Search `PredicateBuilder` and apply.

Comment: Thank you that was a big help!